# removing chroot done by ubuntu touch sdk

Tags: mount, ubuntu-touch, chroot, sdk

How do I remove all the `chroot` the *Ubuntu touch SDK* has made? I can't find anything in the app.
When I do a `mount` from a terminal, I get this :

```
click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386 on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb} type overlayfs (rw,lowerdir=/var/lib/schroot/union/underlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb},upperdir=/var/lib/schroot/union/overlay/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb})
/proc on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb}/proc type none (rw,bind)
/sys on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb}/sys type none (rw,bind)
/dev on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb}/dev type none (rw,bind)
/dev/pts on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb}/dev/pts type none (rw,bind)
/home on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb}/home type none (rw,rbind)
/tmp on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb}/tmp type none (rw,bind)
/run/shm on /var/lib/schroot/mount/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-i386-ucca-1000-{32be949d-df4e-486b-a43e-9762cbe720eb}/run/shm type none (rw,bind)
```

Answer (score 1):

i sussed it i removed

/etc/schroot/chroot.d/-ubuntu-sdk*
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/-ubuntu-sdk*

rebooted and problem sorted :)

thanks wayne :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar question. I was able to list all of them with `schroot -l` and include sessions with `schroot -la`

I found this: [Removing a chroot environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893978/removing-a-chroot-environment)

I ran `schroot -e -c <SESSION>` on each of the sessions listed.

While the schroots still exist when listing with -la, none of the sessions do and my `mount` output is clean.