# Remove non-listed click target

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, chroot

I want to write an app for Ubuntu Touch and test it on my *Aquaris BQ 4.5 Ubuntu Edition*. I failed big time setting it up though and now ended up having no according click target:

When I go to the devices tab in the Ubuntu-SDK, it tells me that there is currently no kit defined for my device. Clicking *Autocreate* it tells me, that there is no compatible chroot installed. Choosing a *armfh 15.04* and entering my password I get:

> The click target click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf exists already

Running `sudo click list` returns nothing and `sudo click unregister --user=phablet click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf` returns

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in <module>
>           sys.exit(main())
>       File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main
>           return mod.run(args)
>       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/unregister.py", line 55, in run
>           old_version = registry.get_version(package)
>    gi._glib.GError: Cannot get password file entry for phablet: Success

but changes nothing. I'm a little stuck here.

`ls /var/lib/schroot/chroots/` returns only `click-ubuntu-sdk-14.04-i386`, which is my OS. But in my confusion I once manually deleted the `/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.04-i386`-Folder.

Anyone any Idea how to reset all this? I would hate to have to reinstall Ubuntu.

P.S.: Creating any OTHER Click Target via *Tools->Options->Ubuntu->Create Click Target* works flawlessly.

Comment: The `click list` and `click unregister` commmands are for managing installed packages, not for managing the chroots used by the SDK, btw.

Answer (score 6):

I found an unexpected solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594686/removing-chroot-done-by-ubuntu-touch-sdk?rq=1). So I continued my bad behaviour of just deleting things and ran `sudo rm -R /etc/schroot/chroot.d/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf` and taadaaa! I can create a click target for *armfh 15.04* now.

Thanks Wayne :D