# Removing a chroot environment

Tags: chroot

I was following these steps to install ros indigo on a chroot environment on my Ubuntu 15.10 
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingIndigoInChroot

But I screwed some things up and I want to remove the chroot environment and restart the steps all over again on a clean slate. 
I googled it and found many posts saying I should just remove the /srv/chroot/indigo_trusty folder but when I tried some of the subdirectories couldn't be removed because they were 'busy'.

I tried to ignore it and use debootstrap to create another folder with the name 'indigo' as another chroot environment. But after it was done when I use schroot -l it only shows the old one 'indigo_trusty'.

What should I do to get rid of all chroot and start all over again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove its conf file that you've created earlier. `schroot -l` shows the information from them.

There may be some things mounted by it. See `cat /etc/mtab`. If you're not sure which ones, a reboot will probably unmount them.

[Removing sessions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295644/146335):

```
# list all sessions:
schroot --list --all-sessions
# if the above command does not work, just type `mount`. The bind mount
# points with something like this in the mount path is the session name you want to get:
precise-a4aac8e0-663c-4fec-8fb2-16e4b06557e3 (<chroot_name>-<id>)

# now run this to properly end the session:
schroot -e -c precise-ca6c72e4-0e9f-4721-8a0e-cca359e2c2fd
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. But I still cannot remove the folder of the old chroot even after the reboot.
sudo rm -r indigo_trusty
[sudo] password for ahmedn1: 
rm: cannot remove ‘indigo_trusty/tmp’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘indigo_trusty/home’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘indigo_trusty/proc’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘indigo_trusty/sys’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘indigo_trusty/dev’: Device or resource busy

Comment: So schroot is still mounting them at boot, so it has still some configuration bits remaining. Maybe there are sessions left. Try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295644/146335 (basically, list and end sessions). Also, you can `apt-get --purge` all schroot packages - that should remove all the configs and chroots, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and I could delete the chroot folder after I ended the session.