# Can not delete chroot after aborting it's creation

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, delete, chroot

I am trying to set up a chroot and I ran

```bsh
sudo qemu-debootstrap --arch=amd64 stretch /srv/chroot/focal-amd64
```

during the second stage i realized that I wanted `focal`, not `stretch`. Copy & paste error.
So I hit ctrl + c and wanted to try again.

```bsh
sudo rm -rf /srv/chroot/focal-amd64/*
```

however i get spammed with

```
rm: cannot remove '/srv/chroot/focal-amd64/proc/[...]': Operation not permitted
```

I tried setting write permissions to directories with

```
find -type d | xargs chmod +rwx
```

with the same errors. No matter what I try to do it seems like I can't delete the folder anymore to try again.

Before, when I let the chroot creation finish, I was able to delete the directory without any problems afterwards, it's only after I interrupted this one that this happens.

Comment: [This solution might help](https://askubuntu.com/a/894026/1222991) 

Comment: I had the same problem using Ubuntu under WSL. Running `wsl --shutdown` and then deleting the folder from explorer fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, [this solution might help](https://askubuntu.com/a/894026/1222991).

I managed by unplugging the hard drive and putting it into another machine and deleting the folder there without any issues.